# Avoid CSS expressions

Tags: html, css, yslow, css-expressions

I understand what a CSS expression is, YSlow is reporting that my page is using one:

```
Grade B on Avoid CSS expressions

There are a total of 1 expression

    inline <style> tag #3 (1 expression)
```

However, I cannot find where this is coming from? I tried searching all my files for the word "expression" (trying to find the expression() function) and am coming up blank. Is there anything else that YSlow could be considering a css expression that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YSlow claims that you have an inline style, so at least it is not from a css file. If you can't find the `<style>` in your own html, something else is adding this to your code.

This could maybe an external JavaScript, or maybe it comes from an browser extension you added, e.g a developer tool.

In your browser debug console type `document.getElementsByTagName("style")` to list all `<style>` in your generated document

Comment: Found it, the all.js file that facebook puts on your page is using an expression. Thanks for the troubleshooting tip!